# How to know which application (context) started/bound a service

Tags: android, service, android-context

I have a Service that is in another package.
How to know which activity or application (context) has started or bound that service, knowing that many applications can access (bind) this service in the same device?

I start/bind the service this way:

```
    private void initService() {
        connection = new MyServiceConnection();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("br.ufc.great.loccam", "br.ufc.great.loccam.service.SysSUService");
        context.startService(i);
        boolean ret = context.bindService(i, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.d(appId, "initService() bound with " + ret);
    }
```

There is a way to get the context of the application that bound the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can [call `getCallingUid()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingUid()) and/or [`getCallingPid()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#getCallingPid()) on `Binder` from the service to attempt to discern what invoked the request.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. I need to get the context of the application, cause i want to acess the application assets folder on the service. Its possible??

Comment: @WitaloBenicio: If you are writing both the client and the service, the simplest thing is for you to pass in the application ID of the client. Otherwise, you're welcome to try to reverse-engineer that via the aforementioned methods on `Binder`, along with `PackageManager`. Once you have the application ID, [use `createPackageContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get a `Context` that points to the assets, resources, etc. of the other app.

Comment: To use createPackageContext() i need to pass a String with the package of the application that i want the context. But how to get the name of the package from the running Service is the problem...

Comment: I have to know the context for each application that binds the Service.

Comment: @WitaloBenicio: "But how to get the name of the package from the running Service is the problem" -- as I wrote, if you are writing both the client and the service, the simplest thing is for you to pass in the application ID of the client. Otherwise, you're welcome to try to reverse-engineer that via the aforementioned methods on Binder, along with PackageManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can get process id at the best from Binder.

If you want to locate app package name from process id, you will have to search through the [`RunningAppProcessInfo.pid`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html#pid) of all the values of [`ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses())

But if you are writing both the Service and Client code, then you can just  write some extra code for client code to identify context after connecting.